# Stripe cancellation of subscription not working Django

Tags: django, stripe-payments, subscription

I'm trying to create a cancellation page to remove a subscription. However, it's not working. In that, I cannot find the customer when I try to call Stripe API.

The customer and subscription I think are being created, at least, the charge is going through.

Here is where I create the subscription in views.py:

```
def charge(request): 
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')
        user = request.user
        plan = 'plan_xxxxxx'
        order_number = X
        customer = stripe.Customer.create(description='Membership', 
            source=token,
            email=user.email, 
            plan=plan)

        charge = stripe.Subscription.create(
            customer=customer.id,
            items=[{'plan': plan}]
            )
    return render(request, 'charge.html')
```

Here is where I try to cancel the subscription:

```
def cancel_subscription(request):
    customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve('request.user.stripe_id')
    customer.cancel_subscription(at_period_end=True)
    return render(request, 'cancel.html')
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Request cus_xxxxxxxx: No such customer: request.user.stripe_id
```

Comment: Why are you passing `request.user.stripe_id` as a string?

Comment: As @dan-klasson notes, you're passing the string literal of `'request.user.stripe_id'`. Remove the quotes around that and you should be good to go.

Comment: No, it should work that way. It's currently passing the customer id - req_WaSiM7HgafPosC. If I remove the strings, then get this error: 'User' object has no attribute 'stripe_id'

Comment: That's because you need to save the customer id to your user model in your `charge` view. Like call it `stripe_customer_id`. Then pass that into your `Customer.retrieve` constructor.